# Question about Threads and Timer object at an interval time

Tags: java

I just need to refresh a ListView with a Feed, which you recommend me for this? A thread? A timer object? I was thinking use a Timer Object with an interval time.

But i am thinking at the moment when a user leave the activity and maybe the timer could not be stopped.

what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a ScheduledExecutorService:[ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

The link I have provided has a code example.

Comment: @papachan, if this answer solved your problem, consider clicking the checkbox underneath the voting controls to mark the answer as accepted.